# Deploying EJB 2.0 .jar on JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x

I have netBeans so i can't deploy Ejb 2.0 on JBoss 7.1.1 so can nyone tell me howcan I deploy it on JBoss 7.1.1?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the error you're encountering?

Answer (score 0):

When you start the server in standalone mode, you can just copy your resulting .ear or .jar file into the `standalone/deployments` folder to get it deployed. This is independent of NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for EJB 2.x and EJB 1.x on Jboss 7.1. You have to use older versions of JBoss server. 
It would be better if you upgrade to EJB3.x which is supported on JBoss 7.1, or wait for new version of JBoss server.